# notepad++ portable remembers session even though I tell it not to

Tags: notepad++

[image]

As per screenshot, I've already told Notepad++ not to remember my session when I launch it next time. However, every time I launch it, it shows my Autohotkey.ahk file. any idea what's wrong?

Comment: May be some configuration file does not save that setting. Download the zip or 7z file from notepad++ website. Extract it anywhere, use it.